# Mouse position onscroll

Tags: javascript

This is working : http://jsfiddle.net/9NDXF/1/ when I write onmousemove, but this is not : http://jsfiddle.net/9NDXF/7/ when I write onscroll.

How can I have the mouse position onscroll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the scroll event has no pageX property. Scrolls suck. Here's a nice [article on mouse scroll events](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/08/javascript-mouse-scroll-event-down-example.html), and a [jsFiddle of the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CEvYx/1/).

The only way to "get the mouse position on scroll" is to have recorded it at some earlier time, then access it when needed. I would put a lot of thought into why you think this is a good idea first though: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NDXF/21/)

```
var mousePostion = {clientX:0,clientY:0};

function record(e)
{
    mousePostion = {
        clientX: e.clientX,
        clientY: e.clientY
    };
}
function print(e)
{
   document.getElementById("x").value=mousePostion.clientX;
   document.getElementById("y").value=mousePostion.clientY;
}
window.onmousemove=record;
window.onscroll=print;​
```

Comment: I edited the question. I wanted to know the position of the mouse but not "why".

Comment: I want the position of the mouse not the amount of scrolling (delta)

Comment: I have included a hack, if you feel that this is something you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

onscroll is when the user scrolls the screen. minimize the jsFiddle so there's a scroll bar, and then scroll with it. You'll see values populated. "e" is undefined.

```
function test(e)
{
    alert(e);

    var doc=document.documentElement;
    var body=document.body;
    if(e.pageX)
    {
        document.getElementById("x").value=e.pageX;
        document.getElementById("y").value=e.pageY;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("x").value=e.clientX+(doc&&doc.scrollLeft||body&&body.scrollLeft||0)-(doc&&doc.clientLeft||body&&body.clientLeft||0);
        document.getElementById("y").value=e.clientY+(doc&&doc.scrollTop||body&&body.scrollTop||0)-(doc&&doc.clientTop||body&&body.clientTop||0);
    }
}
window.onscroll=test;​
```

Comment: @user1365010 "e" is undefined with your onscroll function.

Answer (score 0):

read this refernence hope it help
http://javascriptmagic.blogspot.com/2006/09/getting-scrolling-position-using.html